tabulator - I upgraded from 5.5 to 6.2 and now my tickCross is not working
I upgraded to 6.2 today from 5.5 and now my one table that uses tickCross is not working. this is the tickCross that a user can check or uncheck. can someone let me know what is the problem. the documentation does not look like it changed for it.
I populate the table via an AJAX call.
I tried setting the tickCross column title to true, TRUE, 1, "true" and "TRUE" in teh jason that is passed to the table and the table just locks up with loading data.
this exact same code works in version 5.5. All I did was upgrade to version 6.2 with no code changes to this section and it will not work.

Nothing has changed in that formatter in the during those releases, do you have a link to a JS fiddle that demos the issue?
